# Long range wireless H.264 video streaming

Tags: wireless-networking, streaming

I am streaming H.264 through Wi-Fi. The distance is quite long for the Wi-Fi and it causes tons of packet loss.

The resulting video is nearly useless due to the packet loss.

I have tried to reduce the resolution of the stream and lower the frame rate, but neither worked.

Are there any better solutions to this situation? Like increase the density of P-frames?

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I'd attack it by improving my link quality rather than lowering my video quality.

Either that or buffer your stream longer, especially if you're playing prerecorded content.

Increasing P-frames at the cost of B-frames reduces inter-frame dependencies and thus makes your stream more robust, but it comes at a cost of higher bandwidth, which your link does not seem to afford you. Increasing P-frames at the cost of I-frames reduces your bandwidth but increases inter-frame dependencies, so if you lose an I-frame your stream looks crappy for longer.

Have you used tools like `iperf` to characterize your bandwidth, and maybe `sudo ping -fs 1472` to characterize your packet loss rate? Have you looked at higher-gain directional antennas? Are you already using Wi-Fi equipment designed for long-range point-to-point links?